# Check if XX seconds have elapsed since time in 'timestamp with time zone' format

Tags: python, time

I have a db record created with Django with a ‘created_at' field in the format 'timestamp with time zone': 2017-01-13 14:12:18.307877+00:00.

I need to check if 30 seconds have elapsed between that time and now.
Should I first convert it to epoch time ? If yes how, without being hit by timezone issues ?

Comment: Use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module to convert to a datetime object then you can subtract and compare.

Comment: If you remove the `:` from the time zone, then this is `datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-01-13 14:12:18.307877+0000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the string

```
2017-01-13 14:12:18.307877+00:00
```

we can use the [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function to produce a `datetime` object that we can then do time arithmetic with.

First, we remove the last `:`, because the format for timezones that `datetime` uses is `+0000` not `+00:00`.  Then we hand that string to `strptime` along with a format string.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
s = '2017-01-13 14:12:18.307877+00:00'
s = s[:-3]+s[-2:]
pat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
then = datetime.strptime(s, pat)
if datetime.now(then.tzinfo) - then < timedelta(0, 30): 
    print("It has been less than 30 seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a datetime object, then you can subtract another datetime object and get a timedelta, where you can ask elapsed time.

`d1 = datetime(2017, 1, 1) # create datetime at 2017-01-01T00:00`

`d0 = datetime.now()`

`diff = (d0 - d1).seconds`

`if diff > 30:`

`pass`

The datetime method takes an optional tzinfo, which you can use the set the timezone. This is just a subclass of datetime.tzinfo

Example with GMT +1

```
 class GMT1(tzinfo):
     def utcoffset(self, dt):
         return timedelta(hours=1) + self.dst(dt)
     def dst(self, dt):
         # DST starts last Sunday in March
         d = datetime(dt.year, 4, 1)   # ends last Sunday in October
         self.dston = d - timedelta(days=d.weekday() + 1)
         d = datetime(dt.year, 11, 1)
         self.dstoff = d - timedelta(days=d.weekday() + 1)
         if self.dston <=  dt.replace(tzinfo=None) < self.dstoff:
             return timedelta(hours=1)
         else:
             return timedelta(0)
     def tzname(self,dt):
          return "GMT +1"
```

Then you can do

```
d0 = datetime(2017, 1, 1, tzinfo=GMT1())
```

Comment: Does this respect timezones though?

Comment: @Tagc it uses the default one defined by the running OS. But i updated the answer to take into count timezone.